# Jest testing expect throws TypeError: (0 , _diff.structuredPatch) is not a function

Tags: jestjs

I use jest testing for a reactjs project. When I evaluate two different objects the test fails, but instead of displaying a comparison, it just throws an error.

For strings it works fine, but when I evaluate objects, it just throws the following error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _diff.structuredPatch) is not a function
```

libraries:

- jest: 22.4.2

os: Windows

node: 8.9.4

example test:

```
  test('test', () => {
    const objectA = {
      foo: 'bar'
    };
    const objectB = {
      bar: 'foo'
    };

    expect(objectA).toEqual(objectB);
  });
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Regards
Cornel

Comment: What happens if you won't use `enzyme-to-json` module? Can you just mount `ComplexComponent` and, for example, `find` some DOM node there?

Comment: I can find dome nodes, simulate clicks ect fine with correct results. It's just using expect with complex components (objects) is throwing this error

Comment: I just thought that it's maybe `enzyme-to-json` issue, not  `expect`. For example `expect(wrapper.find('button')).toHaveLength(1)` can work(assuming your `ComplexComponent` have one button in it).

Comment: Those assertions do work :) it only when I pass more complex javascript objects into the expect/toEqual/toMatchSnapShot functions it fails

Comment: Ok, than maybe difference is in components code... Can you update question with both simple and complex components?

Comment: updated. I removed all enzyme and react related code and issue persists

Comment: Thanks, problem is much cleaner now. But I still can't reproduce it:)
I found that code `var _structuredPatch = (0, _diff.structuredPatch)('', '', a, b, '', '', options)` exists in module `jest-diff`, so maybe there is the root. Guys [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/3429) talks about some indentation problems... One last advice - can you completely remove your `node_modules` and make `npm i`? Maybe this will help...

Comment: I tried that. Also cleared the npm cache just to be sure, but I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that version of `node_modules/jest-matcher-utils` is matches version of `node_modules/jest` .

In my case the reason of same problem was conflicting packages, which depend on different versions of `jest` packages (`24.x` vs `26.x`). In my case it was `jest-serial-runner`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-serial-runner": "^1.1.0",  <--- depends on jest 24.x
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.3",
    ...
  }
```